# MPEG - the maximum range for R,G,B?

Tags: encoding, mpeg, video-standards, dvd

There are sentences:
For analog video or MPEG (including DVD) output, the maximum range for R,G,B is [16, 235] (8-bit).
For YUV, the maximum range for intensity (Y) is [16, 235] (8-bit).

Is this saying correct ? I'm thinking that the ***first*** sentence contains an error. MPEG has YCbCr encoding ..
What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MPEG-2 video is stored as YCbCr, but video editing programs (like [Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/docs/split_manual_en/cinelerra_cv_manual_en_14.html#SEC218)) convert the samples to RGB for processing during editing. That range is 16-235.

From Wikipedia on [YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr)

> Analog YPbPr from analog R'G'B' is derived as follows:
>
> [image]

To get a YUV output in the 16-235 range, the input RGB is also limited.

Comment: Do you use Cinelerra ? Can you confirm it with screenshots?